# How to transpose 2 columns to row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have this table used for surveys in which I only need the comments for answer and comment for question No3 and just the comments for question No4

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| Employee | SurveyNo | Question | Answer | Comment |
+----------+----------+----------+--------+---------+
|   100    |    1     |    1     |Neutral |   NULL  |
|   100    |    1     |    2     |  Hard  |   NULL  |
|   100    |    1     |    3     |  Easy  |  asdfs  |
|   100    |    1     |    4     |  NULL  |  ssafa  |
|   200    |    2     |    1     |  Hard  |   NULL  |
|   200    |    2     |    2     |  Hard  |   NULL  |
|   200    |    2     |    3     |  Easy  |  asdfs  |
|   200    |    2     |    4     |  NULL  |   NULL  |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

And what I´m looking for is something like this

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Employee | surveyNo |Question1 | Question2 | Question3 | CommentsQ3 | Comments |
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
|   100    |    1     | Neutral  |    Hard   |   Easy    |   asdfs    |  ssafa   |
|   200    |    2     |   Hard   |    Hard   |   Easy    |   asdfs    |          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Currently I can get every question but not the comments, I just want the comments for Question No3 and just the comments for Question no4.

But when I include the comments I start getting duplicate rows

```
SELECT  Employee,surveyNo,[1] as Question1,[2] as Question2,[3] as Question3
FROM
(
SELECT Employee,surveyNo,answer FROM Surveys WHERE Question in (1,2,3)
) d
pivot
(
max(answer)
for Question in ([1],[2],[3])
) piv
```

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Employee | surveyNo |Question1 | Question2 | Question3 | 
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|   100    |    1     | Neutral  |    Hard   |   Easy    |
|   200    |    2     |   Hard   |    Hard   |   Easy    |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT Employee, surveyNo,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Question = 1 THEN Answer END) AS Question1 ,
       . . . 
       MAX(CASE WHEN Question = 1 THEN Comment END) AS CommentsQ1,
       . . .
FROM Surveys 
WHERE Question in (1,2,3)
GROUP BY Employee, surveyNo;
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was overcomplicating myself. It also perform really fast.